# How to prove a graph's degree sequence is graphical?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We have a degree sequence $c=(d_1,d_2,d_3,...,d_n)$ and we want to prove it's graphical if and only if the sequence $d=(n-d_1-1,n-d_2-1,n-d_3-1,...,n-d_n-1)$ is graphical. How would approach this? Any help? Thank you

Comment: If $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n$ is the degree sequence og $G$, what is the degree sequence of the complement of $G$?

Comment: Well, the degree sequence of the complementary graph G' would be $n-dn-1$ . But how can I prove that if the G' is graphical, then the original is also graphical?

Comment: "Graphical" just means "is the degree sequence of a graph". So to show the $\implies$ direction, for example, you can assume that $G$ is a graph with degree sequence $c$, and show that a graph exists with degree sequence $d$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I understand that a graphical sequence is just a degree sequence that corresponds to a graph G. I also understand the the degree sequence of the complement of G would be $n-dn-1$. However, I fail to make the connection on how to prove the "IFF" part, meaning that only when the degree sequence of the complement of G is graphical then the degree sequence of G is graphical.